# IdentityServer getting claims to appear when using reference token

Tags: c#, authentication, identityserver3

I have found this to be really really confusing and can't find any documentation anywhere. I wish I had not bothered moving to identity server, what with all the problems I have had....
Anyway, the current issue is that when I authenticate, no claims are being based to the **User.Identity**.

I tried to use the **ClaimsTransformer** to add my claims, [but it turns out that you can't use DI to get database claims](http://benfoster.io/blog/customising-claims-transformation-in-aspnet-core-identity) using the **ClaimsTransformer**. So I had to come up with another solution.

I found after a lot of digging around that there is a **ClaimsProvider** that you can use. But when I add it, I cannot authorise my request.
This is my config **before** I added the **ClaimsProvider**:

```
public static class Config
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Configures identity server
    /// </summary>
    public static void ConfigureIdentityServer(this IAppBuilder app, CormarConfig config)
    {
        // Create our options
        var identityServerOptions = new IdentityServerOptions
        {
            SiteName = "Cormar API",
            SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),
            IssuerUri = "https://cormarapi-test.azurewebsites.net",

            LoggingOptions = new LoggingOptions
            {
                EnableHttpLogging = true,
                EnableWebApiDiagnostics = true,
                EnableKatanaLogging = true,
                WebApiDiagnosticsIsVerbose = true
            },

            Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory().Configure(config),

            // Disable when live
            EnableWelcomePage = true
        };

        // Setup our auth path
        app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp => { idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(identityServerOptions); });
    }


    /// <summary>
    ///     Configures the identity server to use token authentication
    /// </summary>
    public static void ConfigureIdentityServerTokenAuthentication(this IAppBuilder app, HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://cormarapi-test.azurewebsites.net/identity",
            DelayLoadMetadata = true,
            ValidationMode = ValidationMode.Both,
            RequiredScopes = new[] {"api"},

            ClientId = "api",
            ClientSecret = "8at?7nAtaB!E"
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Loads the certificate
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
    {
        var certPath = $"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}App_Data\\idsrv3test.pfx";
        var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        var certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "3A1AFB6E1DC5C3F341E63651542C740DA4148866", false);
        certStore.Close();

        // If we are on azure, get the actual self signed certificate, otherwise return the test one
        return certCollection.Count > 0 ? certCollection[0] : new X509Certificate2(certPath, "idsrv3test");
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Configure the identity service factory with custom services
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static IdentityServerServiceFactory Configure(this IdentityServerServiceFactory factory, CormarConfig config)
    {
        var serviceOptions = new EntityFrameworkServiceOptions {ConnectionString = config.SqlConnectionString};
        factory.RegisterOperationalServices(serviceOptions);
        factory.RegisterConfigurationServices(serviceOptions);
        factory.CorsPolicyService = new Registration<ICorsPolicyService>(new DefaultCorsPolicyService {AllowAll = true}); // Allow all domains to access authentication

        factory.Register(new Registration<DbContext>(dr => dr.ResolveFromAutofacOwinLifetimeScope<DbContext>()));
        factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(dr => dr.ResolveFromAutofacOwinLifetimeScope<IUserService>());
        factory.ClientStore = new Registration<IClientStore>(dr => dr.ResolveFromAutofacOwinLifetimeScope<IClientStore>());
        factory.ScopeStore = new Registration<IScopeStore>(dr => dr.ResolveFromAutofacOwinLifetimeScope<IScopeStore>());

        return factory;
    }
}
```

When it is set up like this and I invoke it in my **Startup.cs**:

```
app.ConfigureIdentityServer(scope.Resolve<CormarConfig>());
app.ConfigureIdentityServerTokenAuthentication(config);
app.UseWebApi(config);
```

All works fine (with the exception of Claims). I can authenticate and I can authorise my requests.
Now I need to get my **UserClaims**, so I created my **ClaimsProvider** like this:

```
public class ClaimsProvider: DefaultClaimsProvider
{

    private readonly IUserStore<User> _userStore;
    public ClaimsProvider(IUserService userService, IUserStore<User> userStore)
        : base(userService)
    {
        _userStore = userStore;
    }

    public override async Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> GetAccessTokenClaimsAsync(ClaimsPrincipal subject, Client client, IEnumerable<Scope> scopes, ValidatedRequest request)
    {
        var id = subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = await _userStore.FindByIdAsync(id);

        return user.Claims.Select(ModelFactory.Create).ToList();
    }
}
```

Then I added it to my **IdentityServerServiceFactory Configure** method like this:

```
factory.ClaimsProvider = new Registration<IClaimsProvider>(dr => dr.ResolveFromAutofacOwinLifetimeScope<IClaimsProvider>());
```

The **ClaimsProvider** is registered with **Autofac** like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<ClaimsProvider>().As<idsrv.IClaimsProvider>().InstancePerDependency();
```

I can still authenticate and get my token, but as soon as I try to access any endpoint using my token I get this error:

> invalid bearer token received

I have no idea why. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was totally looking in the wrong place here.
To add **Claims** to the user, you have to override **GetProfileDataAsync** in the custom **UserService**. I had done that before, but the claims were not being persisted. Then I read about the **ScopeClaims**. In my case, my **Claim** was of type "role" so I just added a new **ScopeClaim** with a name of role and then when I logged in, I saw that **GetProfileDataAsync** was invoked and sure enough, the claims were added to my **User.Identity**.
As an example, here is what my **GetProfileDataAsync** looks like:

```
    public override async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var subject = context.Subject;
        var requestedClaimTypes = context.RequestedClaimTypes;

        var user = await _userProvider.FindByIdAsync(subject.GetSubjectId());
        if (user == null) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid user id");

        var claims = GetClaimsFromUser(user);
        if (requestedClaimTypes != null && requestedClaimTypes.Any()) claims = claims.Where(m => requestedClaimTypes.Contains(m.Type));

        context.IssuedClaims = claims;
    }

    private IEnumerable<Claim> GetClaimsFromUser(User model)
    {
        var claims = model.Claims.Select(ModelFactory.Create).ToList();

        if (model.EmailConfirmed) claims.Add(new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.EmailVerified, model.EmailConfirmed ? "true": "false"));

        return claims;
    }
```